# Should I run Dispose before application exit?

Tags: c#, dispose

Should I run Dispose before application exit?

For example, I create many objects and some of they have event subscribe:

```
 var myObject=new MyClass();
 myObject.OnEvent+=OnEventHandle;
```

And, for example, at my work I should use classes with `IDisposable` interface.
Then, I decide to close app and do this:

```
Enviroment.Exit(-1);
```

Am I right?

Should I call `Dispose` to all objects, which implements IDisposable interface?
Can a memory leak occur?

P.S. This is server-side app, using WCF, MQ.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call Dispose directly in most circumstances, because your `IDisposable` objects should be wrapped in using statements.

Comment: As a general rule, all classes that implement `IDisposable` should be consumed in a `using` statement

Comment: As others said, you should manage your options properly using `using` statements. But to answer your question: When the process terminates, its memory is freed by the operating system, so you technically do not need to dispose your own objects yourself, but it’s good practice to do so properly anyway.

Comment: IDisposable is a *contract*.  Gets abused a lot, like using it to unsubscribe events.  But no matter how badly you abuse it, you can never leak memory after your program is terminated.  None is left.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this *specific* case, you may choose not to `Dispose`. I was sure I recollected a Raymond Chen analogy about not emptying the bins just before you have a building demolished.<sup>1</sup>

Your entire process is about to disappear. There's no need for *you* to do any cleanup of internal resources, since the OS is about to reclaim all of its resources.

However, you have to weigh this up against it a) appearing non-standard, b) potentially triggering warnings from e.g. stylecop, versus the expected reward in taking *slightly* less time to exit - do you really need to optimize this part of your application?

As others have commented, I'd usually choose to still wrap my disposable objects in `using`s, even though it may be strictly unnecessary in this case.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is the [one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683) about not doing anything in DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. The reasoning is similar.

Comment: Btw wrapping objects in `using` _blindly_ could cause performance issues even with some framework classes (for example, `HttpClient`) and unfortunately we don't know much about the classes being disposed in this case.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov - agreed. But if we take the context of the question as "If I wasn't just about to exit, I would and should call `Dispose` on X", then that's how I'm trying to answer.

Comment: Another issue is that some classes may acquire resources the OS knows nothing about (e.g. the application sent a command to some outside machine to grant exclusive access to something until further notice; if an application never calls `Dispose`, the remove machine will never be told to release the resource).