# IDisposable cascade

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class to model an external device via TCP/IP. This class creates a client, which is basically a wrapper for System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient and instances of this class are held by an application class.

according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#cascade-dispose-calls if a class owns a field that implements IDisposable it should also implement IDisposable.

So in my situation, TcpClient implements IDisposable, therefore my client class has to implement IDisposable, therefore my external device class has to implement IDisposable, therefore my application class has to implement IDisposable.

Sounds cumbersome, so I´m questioning if thats the right way to do it?

```
public class Client : IDisposable
{
    private TcpClient _tcpClient;
    ...

    public void Connect()
    {
        _tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        if (!_tcpClient.ConnectAsync(address, port).Wait(1000))
        ...
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _tcpClient?.Dispose();
        _tcpClient = null;
    }

    #region IDisposable
    ...
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        if (disposing)
        {
            _tcpClient?.Dispose();
            _tcpClient = null;
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
    #endregion

    ...
}


public class SM15k : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Client _client;
    ...

    public SM15k()
    {
        _client = new Client();
    }

    #region IDisposable
    ...
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        if (disposing)
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
    #endregion
    ...
}


public class App : IDisposable
{
    private SM15k _SM15k;

    #region IDisposable
    ...
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        if (disposing)
        {
            _SM15k?.Dispose();
            _SM15k = null;
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
    #endregion
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using IoC?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: "therefore my application class has to implement IDisposable" - no, your application class should trigger the disposing once it has finished using the external device class. Or at least there's nothing to call ApplicationClass.Dispose(), so there's no need to add the interface there.

Comment: Should you do it? **In theory** - yes. In practice, it doesn't matter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158572/34092

Comment: @mjwills For managed resources that might be fine and cleaned up on shutdown, but if your application has allocated unmanaged resources (such as a tcp port) it won't get automatically closed. Also, this class might be reused several times in a long running application and then it should be done no matter what.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Re-use (your latter point) is a valid point. In terms of the TCP port - you are saying it won't get closed when the process dies? Can you point me to somewhere to read more about this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged
"The most common types of unmanaged resources are objects that wrap operating system resources, such as files, windows, network connections, or database connections. Although the garbage collector is able to track the lifetime of an object that encapsulates an unmanaged resource, it doesn't know how to release and clean up the unmanaged resource."

Comment: It will most likely time out and be closed after a while, but it won't be automaticly released just by the final cleanup or the application exiting. I have no more exact source then the link above and my own experiences for this.

Comment: A quick google found lots of samples of this over on SF though: https://www.google.com/search?q=not+releasing+tcp+ports+on+exit+site:serverfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is the correct way to do it.

Since you have dependencies that needs to be disposed you'll have to make sure that they are disposed all the way down. Otherwise, when you dispose your "external device class" the `TcpClient` at the bottom won't be properly disposed and you might get a resource leak (ports remaining open for example).